# How do I make very long lines of code human readable in R?

Tags: r, editor

Here's several style guides for writing R code [1](https://style.tidyverse.org/), [2](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.html), and [3](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html). They all deal with relatively "nice" examples that I'm able to follow. But let me paste some actual code I'm working with from R:

```
mutate(DCloDate = min(Date),
       AgeEOM = if_else(Type == "Date Created", as.integer(as.Date(ceiling_date(Month, unit = "month")) - days(1) - Date), -1L * as.integer(as.Date(ceiling_date(Month, unit = "month")) - days(1) - DCloDate))) %>%
```

This thing is just a monster. Here's several attempts at keeping things less than 80 characters wide on my text editor, it seems like one bad option after another. What are objective ways I could transform this code mess into easy human readable code?

It's the indenting and all that, that I need. Thank you.

```
# Attempt 1
mutate(
  DCloDate = min(Date),
  AgeEOM = if_else(
    Type == "Date Created", 
    as.integer(as.Date(ceiling_date(Month, unit = "month")) - days(1) - Date), 
    -1L * as.integer(as.Date(
      ceiling_date(Month, unit = "month")) - days(1) - DCloDate))) %>% 

# Attempt 2
mutate(DCloDate = min(Date),
       AgeEOM = if_else(Type == "Date Created", 
                        as.integer(as.Date(ceiling_date(Month, 
                                                        unit = "month")) - 
                                     days(1) - Date), 
                        -1L * as.integer(as.Date(ceiling_date(Month, 
                                                              unit = "month")) - 
                                           days(1) - DCloDate))) %>% 

# Attempt 3
mutate(DCloDate = min(Date),
       AgeEOM = if_else(
         Type == 
           "Date Created", 
         as.integer(as.Date(ceiling_date(Month, unit = "month")) - 
                      days(1) - Date), 
         -1L * as.integer(as.Date(ceiling_date(Month, unit = "month")) - 
                            days(1) - 
                            DCloDate))) %>% 

# Attempt 4, 5, 6 ...
just gets worse and worse
```

Comment: if `as.Date(ceiling_date(Month, unit = "month"))` was put in an intermediate variable with a short but speaking name, the `ifelse`part would become readable enough for me. YMMV  The pipe at the end suggests, you are using pipes and afterwards complain about lines being to long. Again: Consider using an intermediate variable and splitting things up becomes easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried select all in RStudio and then Ctrl-Shift-A to automatically reformat code?